# How to detect inline css style with jquery (to stop slider)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider

I have a slider, what animates when next/prev buttons clicked. I had an idea, to stop the function if the slider reaches the minimum (0px) and the maximum (1200px) in the animation. How can I detect jquery added inline css? Or any ideas of how to "stop" the slider?

My code:

```
$('.next').click(function(){
    $('#portfolio-slider').animate({
        left: "-=400",
    }, 300);       
});

$('.prev').click(function(){
    $('#portfolio-slider').animate({
        left: "+=400",
    }, 300);       
});
```

JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tDrqT/3/

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a nice fiddle that shows your slider with limits at the first and last image. It uses the jQUery `position()` function to get the location of the slider as well as the location of the last image and uses that information to limit the movement of the slider.

http://jsfiddle.net/tDrqT/14/

```
//get the position and width of the last image
var lastPicPos = $('#portfolio-slider').children('img').last().position().left;

function getLeftPos() {
     return - $('#portfolio-slider').position().left;   
}

var onUpdate = function() {
    $('#info').text("0 <= " + getLeftPos() + " <= " + lastPicPos);
};

onUpdate();

$('.next').click(function(){
    if (getLeftPos() < lastPicPos) {
      $('#portfolio-slider').animate({
            left: "-=400",
        }, 300, null, onUpdate);       
    }
});

$('.prev').click(function(){
     if (getLeftPos() > 0) {
      $('#portfolio-slider').animate({
            left: "+=400",
        }, 300, null, onUpdate);
    }
});
```

You will also have to add a div to the top of the html that I used to show some output:

```
<div id="info"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check the position with:

```
$('#portfolio-slider').position().left
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/tDrqT/6/) the fiddle

Answer (score 0):

jQuery.css will return the inline style.

```
$('.next').click(function(){
    $('#portfolio-slider').animate({
            left: "-=400",
        }, 300);       

    console.log($('#portfolio-slider').css('left'));
});

$('.prev').click(function(){
    $('#portfolio-slider').animate({
            left: "+=400",
        }, 300);    

    console.log($('#portfolio-slider').css('left'));
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/tDrqT/5/

You can implement a simple check to see if the slider is at the last image before calling animate.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the style attribute like this

```
if($('#portfolio-slider').attr('style') === 'left: -800px;')
        return
```

Here's a fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/tDrqT/7/

Answer (score 0):

Use `.animate()` and use `step`:

```
var min = 0,
    max = 800;
$('.next').click(function(){
    $('#portfolio-slider').animate({
            left: "-=400",
        }, {
            step: function (now, fx) {
                                    console.log(now);
                if(parseInt(now) <= (max*-1)){
                    $(this).stop();
                    fx.end = fx.start;
                }
            }
        }, 300);       
});

$('.prev').click(function(){
    $('#portfolio-slider').animate({
            left: "+=400",
        }, {
            step: function (now, fx) {
                if(parseInt(now) >= min){
                    $(this).stop();
                    fx.end = fx.start;
                }
            }
        }, 300);       
});
```

DEMO:
http://jsfiddle.net/dirtyd77/AfBkg/

Answer (score 0):

I would check the postition directly. Just look for 0 on the left and -800 on the right. Only perform the animation if you're not going past an edge.

```
$('.next').click(function(){
    if ($('#portfolio-slider').position().left === -800) {
        return;
    }

    $('#portfolio-slider').animate({
            left: "-=400",
        }, 300);       
});

$('.prev').click(function(){
    if ($('#portfolio-slider').position().left === -0) {
        return;
    }
    $('#portfolio-slider').animate({
            left: "+=400",
        }, 300);       
});
```

fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/uFMfa/1/